# Why can't I implement Deref for a specific lifetime?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

```
use std::ops::{Deref};
use std::sync::{MutexGuard};

pub struct MutexGuardRef<'a, T> {
    mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Deref for MutexGuardRef<'a, T> {
    type Target = Option<T>;

    fn deref(&'a self) -> &'a Self::Target {
        &self.mutex_guard.deref().as_ref().map(|x|*x)
    }
}
```

this gives:

```
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(&MutexGuardRef<'a, T>) -> &Option<T>`
              found fn pointer `fn(&'a MutexGuardRef<'a, T>) -> &'a Option<T>`
```

Why can't I implement a trait for a specific lifetime? Why does it have to be all lifetimes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your code that need to be resolved.

## Lifetime

> Why I cannot implement a trait for a specific lifetime? Why it has to
> be all lifetimes?

There is no problem with implementing a trait for a specific lifetime, as in `impl<'a, T> Deref for MutexGuardRef<'a, T>`.  In fact, that's the correct thing to do here.  The compiler error arises as you implement the `deref` method.

I believe the confusion here results from a misunderstanding of lifetime bounds on types, such as `'a` in `MutexGuardRef<'a, T>`.  The `'a` doesn't mean that every value of the type `MutexGuardRef<'a, T>` lives for the duration of `'a`; rather, it means that ***type* itself is bounded by `'a`**, which means that **every *value* lives *at most* for the duration of `'a`.**  We'll call this *restriction 1*.

On the other hand, when you write down `&'a self`, which is short for `self: &'a MutexGuardRef<'a, T>`, you are saying that `*self`, which the reference `self` points to, is **a *value* that is valid for the duration of `'a`**; in other words, it's **a *value* that lives *at least* for the duration of `'a`**, which we'll refer to as *restriction 2*.

I hope this explanation has made things clearer — restriction 1 is necessary, as it's an intrinsic property of the type; however, restriction 2 is not what we are looking for, since dereferencing a `MutexGuardRef` value doesn't require it to live as long as the `Mutex` does.

When we remove both occurrences of `'a` from the implementation of `deref`, we get

```rust
fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target
```

which is short for

```rust
fn deref(self: &MutexGuardRef<'a, T>) -> &Self::Target
```

Restriction 1 is preserved, whereas restriction 2 is lifted.  The compiler is therefore satisfied ...

## Type

... except that it greets us with another error:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:9
   |
8  | impl<'a, T> Deref for MutexGuardRef<'a, T> {
   |          - this type parameter
...
12 |         &self.mutex_guard.deref().as_ref().map(|x|*x)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found struct `Box`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Option<T>`
              found reference `&Option<Box<T>>`
```

revealing a problem of a different kind.

`&Self::Target`, which stands for `&Option<T>`, is a reference to an `Option<T>` that *already exists*.  All we have is a `Mutex<Option<Box<T>>>` — there is no `Option<T>` to point to.

Ideally, we would like `deref` to return an `Option<&T>`, which points to the innermost `T` wrapped in the mutex if any.  However, the `Deref` trait dictates the return type to be of form `&Self::Target`, so our best call is to return `&Option<Box<T>>`.

The result:

```rust
use std::{ops::Deref, sync::MutexGuard};

pub struct MutexGuardRef<'a, T> {
    mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Deref for MutexGuardRef<'a, T> {
    type Target = Option<Box<T>>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &*self.mutex_guard
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5d1a08e07a6f4d41129880c648a9ab2))

Comment: thanks, very concise. However, the intent was to return `Option<&T>` so I don't have to deref the box by myself. The `Box` here is just to store a `dyn Something`. Is it possible to deref to `Option<&T>`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Unfortunately, as indicated in the answer, the `Deref` trait specifies the return type of `deref` to be `&Self::Target`.  I guess you can add a method for that (perhaps called `as_ref`).  It shouldn't cause too much concern in many situations though - after handling the `Option`, auto-deref and coercion will usually take care of the last step.

Comment: But why can't I simply say `type Target = Option<T>`? This is the part I don't get. I understand that we must return `&Self::Target`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I think you're conflating `Option<&T>` and `&Option<T>`.  With `type Target = Option<T>`, you get `&Option<T>`, which assumes that you already have an `Option<T>` (not `T`) set up somewhere in memory, and points to it.  Since we only have a `Mutex<Option<Box<T>>>`, we can do `&Option<Box<T>>`, `&Box<T>`, or `&T`, but not `&Option<T>`.  What we would like is actually `Option<&T>`, which is a nullable reference to `T`, not `&Option<T>`, but the interface of `Deref` prohibits that.

Comment: isn't it the case that the Deref trait allows me setting `type Target= Option<&T>`, but I cannot make this work because I'd have to create the object `Option<&T>` inside the `deref()` function, which would force the reference to be short lived, instead of living in the lifetime of `Self`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Since `deref` returns `&Self::Target`, the return type has to be a reference to something, which `Option<&T>` is not.  If `deref` were allowed to return `Option<&T>`, its implementation would be straightforward using [`as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref), as shown in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb7842c4ae44d3e78bffc0bbf65cd777).

Comment: Indeed, but if it were possible to return `&Option<&T>` it would be ok for me. So `Deref` makes it possible, but lifetime problems arise.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs `&Option<&T>` is not possible, the same way that `&Option<T>` isn't - there is no `Option<&T>` or `Option<T>` in the `Mutex<Option<Box<T>>>` to point to.  Since `Deref` is supposed to be implemented for smart pointers only, it does not support operations on the pointed-to value, such as unwrapping `Option`s.  The logical answer here is simply `&Option<Box<T>>`, and the compiler ensures this - you cannot convince the compiler otherwise ;)